# How to insert and fetch result from fusion table

Tags: php, jquery, google-fusion-tables

I locally setup for fusion table i need to insert and fetch result from fusion table i copy the code from site but it is always generate an error form me
When i try to fetch result and insert result it generate an error form me i am unable to fetch result

```
[
 {
  "error": {
   "code": 403,
   "message": "Access Not Configured",
   "data": [
    {
     "domain": "usageLimits",
     "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
     "message": "Access Not Configured"
    }
   ]
  },
  "id": "gapiRpc"
 }
]

Please help me for fixed id 

Here is my code i am locally setup for this

var clientId = '877036777031-oiac9p32ujf3hoqamrm99lrkavkb72mg.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var apiKey = 'AIzaSyDaeSEkUfh8tSbXyfGb_l4e3uf2lVOFbrI';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';
var tableId = '1SyGe4OV4OeP8OkUScxuYBEmeC4IGSo0me6Tg0RE';
var clientSecret = '1z_OFh5HcxQp_mS2rUkroi-8';
        function handleClientLoad() {
            // Step 2: Reference the API key
            gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
            window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
        }
        function checkAuth() {
            gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
        }
        function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
            var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
            if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                makeApiCall();
            } else {
                authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
                authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
            }
        }

        function handleAuthClick(event) {
            // Step 3: get authorization to use private data
            gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
            return false;
        }

        // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
        function makeApiCall() {
            gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
                var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
                    'userId': 'me'
                });
                request.execute(function(resp) {
                    var heading = document.createElement('h4');
                    var image = document.createElement('img');
                    image.src = resp.image.url;
                    heading.appendChild(image);
                    heading.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resp.displayName));

                    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(heading);
                });
            });
        }
        // Initialize the client, set onclick listeners.
        function initialize() {
            gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
            document.getElementById('create-table').onclick = createTable;
            document.getElementById('insert-data').onclick = insertData;
            document.getElementById('select-data').onclick = selectData;
            window.setTimeout(function() { auth(true); }, 1);
        }

        // Run OAuth 2.0 authorization.
        function auth(immediate) {
            getGAauthenticationToken('bharatjain.aloha@gmail.com', 'aloha@123');
            gapi.auth.authorize({
                client_id: clientId,
                client_secret: clientSecret,
                scope: scopes,
                immediate: immediate
            }, handleAuthResult);
        }

        // Run a request to create a new Fusion Table.
        function createTable() {
            var tableResource = [];
            tableResource.push('{');
            tableResource.push('"Text": "Number",');
            tableResource.push('"columns": [');
            tableResource.push('{ "name": "Name", "type": "STRING" },');
            tableResource.push('{ "name": "Age", "type": "NUMBER" }');
            tableResource.push('],')
            tableResource.push('"isExportable": true');
            tableResource.push('}');
            runClientRequest({
                path: '/fusiontables/v1/tables',
                body: tableResource.join(''),
                method: 'POST'
            }, function(resp) {
                var output = JSON.stringify(resp);
                document.getElementById('create-table-output').innerHTML = output;
                tableId = resp['tableId'];
                document.getElementById('table-id-1').innerHTML = tableId;
                document.getElementById('table-id-2').innerHTML = tableId;
                document.getElementById('insert-data').disabled = false;
                document.getElementById('select-data').disabled = false;
                document.getElementById('create-table').disabled = true;
            });
        }

        // Run a request to INSERT data.
        function insertData() {
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
            var insert = [];
            insert.push('INSERT INTO ');
            insert.push(tableId);
            insert.push(' (Text, Number) VALUES (');
            insert.push("'" + name + "', ");
            insert.push(age);
            insert.push(')');
            query(insert.join(''));
        }

        // Run a request to SELECT data.
        function selectData() {
            query('SELECT * FROM ' + tableId);
        }

        // Send an SQL query to Fusion Tables.
        function query(query) {
            var lowerCaseQuery = query.toLowerCase();
            var path = '/fusiontables/v1/query';
            var callback = function(element) {
                return function(resp) {
                    var output = JSON.stringify(resp);
                    document.getElementById(element).innerHTML = output;
                };
            }
            if (lowerCaseQuery.indexOf('select') != 0 &&
                lowerCaseQuery.indexOf('show') != 0 &&
                lowerCaseQuery.indexOf('describe') != 0) {
                var body = 'sql=' + encodeURIComponent(query);
                runClientRequest({
                    path: path,
                    body: body,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'Content-Length': body.length
                    },
                    method: 'POST',
                    userName: 'bharatjain.jaw@gmail.com',
                    password: 'mayank19jain'
                }, callback('insert-data-output'));

            } else {
                runClientRequest({
                    path: path,
                    params: { 'sql': query }
                }, callback('select-data-output'));
            }
        }

        // Execute the client request.
        function runClientRequest(request, callback) {
            var restRequest = gapi.client.request(request);
            restRequest.execute(callback);
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Fusion Tables JavaScript Example
</h1>
<h2>
    (1) Authorize using OAuth 2.0
</h2>
<p>
    Click Authorize to start the OAuth 2.0 authorization flow. If you have
    already authorized, the button will be disabled.
</p>
<input type="button" id="authorize-button" value="Authorize"><br>

<h2>
    (2) Create Table
</h2>
<p>
    Click "Create Table" to create an exportable Fusion Table called "People"
    with columns "Name" with type "STRING" and "Age" with type "NUMBER".
      <pre>
{
  "name": "People",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "Name",
      "type": "STRING"
    }, {
      "name": "Age",
      "type": "NUMBER"
    }
  ],
  "isExportable": true
}</pre>
</p>
<input type="button" id="create-table" value="Create Table"
       disabled="disabled">
<p id="create-table-output"><i>table response goes here...</i></p><br>

<h2>
    (3) Insert data
</h2>
<p>
    Insert data into the newly created table.
</p>
<pre>INSERT INTO <span id="table-id-1">[table_id]</span> (Name, Age) VALUES ([name], [age])</pre>
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name"><br>
<label>Age:</label>
<input type="age" id="age"><br>
<input type="button" id="insert-data" value="Insert data">
<p id="insert-data-output"><i>insert response goes here...</i></p><br>

<h2>
    (4) Select all the rows from the table
</h2>
<p>
    Select the data that has been inserted into the newly created table.
</p>
<pre>SELECT * FROM <span id="table-id-2">[table_id]</span></pre>
<input type="button" id="select-data" value="Select data">
<p id="select-data-output"><i>select response goes here...</i></p>
</body>
</html>
```